# What is the best way to manage WSUS updates on laptops?

Tags: windows-update, wsus

we have one WSUS server distributing updates to computers in 4 school which are all part of one domain. Each school has a couple of laptop safes and I am trying to figure out a sensible way of distributing WSUS updates to the laptops without it impacting the lessons too much.

Any advice on what would be the best way of doing it?

Comment: Your question is hard to read you might consider working on the clarity of the question

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer, I think, depends on whether you have a reliable person designated for managing the machines. If you do, then the best option is to configure them with AUOption '3' (Notify for Installation), and trust that designated person to *install* the updates at an appropriate time.

If you don't have somebody in the school who can take on that responsibility, then you really only have two other options:

1. Schedule the update installation for after-hours (using AUOption '4') and ask that the machines be left powered on. You'll also have to get a feel for how long it takes from approval, thru download, to the time they're ready for installation. You can help with this by scheduling a shorter detection interval (4 hours, perhaps?) for these machines. Using Deadlines on the approvals to ensure they get done within a specified time period is also something to consider.
2. Do it yourself. That's at least four days a month out of the office doing "field trips" to schools. Not saying this is a functional solution, but it is a possible solution.